# Vim script function: Unexpected characters in :let

Tags: vim

So I'm learning vim script and trying to write a function that toggles (removes/adds) a character in a string and then returns the resulting string (the comments are just for stack overflow, I know how to properly comment in vimscript)

```
function! ToggleStringValue(input, value)
    if a:input =~ value // if the value's there
        let &a:input = substitute(a:input, a:value, "", "") // remove it
    else
        let &a:input .= a:value // otherwise append it
    endif
    return a:input
endfu
```

Example (pseudo) usage:

```
guioptions = ToggleStringValue(guioptions, "m") // should toggle menu bar on/off
```

But I'm getting an error on `line 4` of the function `Unexpected characters in :let`

What am I doing wrong? and is this a good way of writing this function?

Edit: Correct versions after taking notes from Kent's answer:

```
function! ToggleStringValue(input, value)
    let l:result = a:input
    if l:result =~ a:value
        let l:result = substitute(l:result, a:value, "", "")
    else
        let l:result .= a:value
    endif
    return l:result
endfu

function! ToggleMenuBar()
    let &g:guioptions = ToggleStringValue(&g:guioptions, "m")
endfu
```

Comment: I recommend putting answers as a separate answer instead of in the question.

Comment: I just added what I ended up writing after I got the correct answer from @Kent - maybe it will help others coming across this in the future. I'm not sure if what I added is considered a separate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your codes have several problems:

- in vimscript, comment starts with `"`, not `//`, maybe you just put them there to make the question clear, I hope it is like that.
- `&var` means an option, like `let &number=0` to hide line number, same as `set nonumber` If the `var` was not option name, you will catch something like "Unknown Option" or "Option doesn't exist"
- method/function argument with `a:foo`, they cannot be changed, they are readonly. That is, `let a:foo="blah"` won't go. You have to make a copy of them.

Comment: The comments are just for stack overflow

Comment: @vexe post comment after reading my answer through. I thought the comments were for making the codes clear, and I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: Thanks that was very tricky. I keep inserting semi colons, forget a: or l: put & everywhere etc. I was reading Learn VimScript the hard way and now I remember I read that readonly gotcha.